# Sorting each group of data based on the values on a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

My data is look like,

[image]

As you can see, I used the label column in order to group my data and rows with the same label belongs to the same group in this way. Now I want to sort each group based on data on the column "value". For example, I want the above table to be converted to,

[image]

Using Sort & Filter will sort the entire column without considering the label column. Furthermore, the label column goes till 250 and there are also about 20-30 repetition in label numbers. Can you please help me to do this task efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Ribbon, go to the **Home Tab > Sort & Filter > Custom Sort**

[image: custom_sort.png]

In the Sort dialog box, make sure the check box for "*My data has headers*" is checked; then, sort by "*label*", click **Add Level**, then by "*value*" and click OK.

[image: add_level.png]

**Results:**

[image: sort_results.png]

Answer (score 1):

In the Sort procedure you can define levels. So your first level is 'label' and the second level is 'value'.